Why successfully running mysql suddenly stops connecting through php?
Hello everyone: I am getting following error on MySQL 5.4 Windows server 2012;
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php Line Number: 202 Backtrace: File: /var/www/vhosts/sys.lhc.gov.pk/htdoc/application/controllers/Case_management.php Line: 37 Function: _

It doesn't matter, how it worked before. Only current error that matters. Which is quiteclear: eyther mysql is not running, or ona different port, or there is a firewall blocking access to it. Every case is explained in the dupe answer, hence no reason to reopen

Windows 2012 is out of support and needs to be retired. Upgrade to a supported O/S. It won't fix this specific error but it will improve your security and compliance. Judging by your folder name there it looks like you might be hosting government websites on obsolete platforms...I don't expect they'll thank you for that, when there's eventually a security breach.

MySQL 5.4 - never heard of that. But even if you were using the later MySQL 5.5, you would still run a system that is out ouf support since nearly six years
